# C++ 17 copy and delete files with special characters in their names on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++17

I wrote a program that copy a file from a given path(s) to another. It runs well until it meets special character in directory names or in file names. At that moment it stops and throws the error that "No such file or directory".

This is what I done until now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    vector<string> args(argv + 1, argv + argc);

    auto target = args[args.size() - 1];
    fs::path path = target;
    cout << "Destination path: " << target << endl;
    args.erase(args.end());
    for (const auto &source : args) {
        try {
            for (const auto &entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(source)) {
                std::string new_path = target + "\\" + entry.path().relative_path().string();
                //if entry is directory:
                while (true) {
                    if (GetDriveType(const_cast<char *>(path.root_path().string().c_str())) != DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR) {
                        if (fs::is_directory(entry)) {
                            //only if it NOT exists:
                            if (!fs::exists(new_path)) {
                                //create it only if not empty:
                                if (!fs::is_empty(entry)) {
                                    //Creating directory tree structure with empty folders:
                                    try {
                                        fs::create_directories(new_path);
                                    } catch (const std::exception &e) // caught by reference to base
                                    {
                                        std::cout << "When trying to create directory" << new_path
                                                  << "A standard exception was caught, with message '"
                                                  << e.what() << "'\n";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    } else {
                        cout << "Destination path is not available. Sleeping for 3 minutes!" << endl;
                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(180000ms);
                    }
                }

                while (true) {
                    if (GetDriveType(const_cast<char *>(path.root_path().string().c_str())) != DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR) {
                        if ((fs::is_regular_file(entry)) && (fs::exists(entry))) {
                            if (!fs::is_empty(entry)) {
                                if (!fs::exists(new_path)) {
                                    //file does NOT exists in new path:
                                    try {
                                        fs::copy_file(entry.path().string(), new_path);
                                        cout << "Copy file: " << entry.path().string() << endl;
                                        fs::remove(entry);
                                    } catch (const std::exception &e) // caught by reference to base
                                    {
                                        std::cout
                                                << "When trying to get file size and source a standard exception was caught, with message '"
                                                << e.what() << "'\n";
                                    }


                                } else {
                                    //if it exists in new path:
                                    //first try to get file size and if this gives an error then do not copy:
                                    if (fs::file_size(entry.path().string()) >
                                        fs::file_size(entry.path().string())) {
                                        try {
                                            fs::copy_file(entry.path().string(), new_path);
                                            cout << "Replacing file: " << entry.path().string() << endl;
                                            fs::remove(entry);
                                        } catch (const std::exception &e) // caught by reference to base
                                        {
                                            std::cout
                                                    << "When trying to get file size and source a standard exception was caught, with message '"
                                                    << e.what() << "'\n";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        break;
                    } else {
                        cout << "Destination path is not available. Sleeping for 3 minutes!" << endl;
                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(180000ms);
                    }
                }//end while!

            }
        } catch (const std::exception &e) // caught by reference to base
        {
            std::cout << "When recursive through directory tree a standard exception was caught, with message '"
                      << e.what() << "'\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After searching on Google and mostly on stackoverflow for a solution conclusion is that none works.

I tried adding `#define UNICODE` and `#define _UNICODE` at the top of it but it gives even more errors.

I also added `-municode` flag in CMakeLists in CLion but also not working (it compiles but gives runtime error).

Also tried to replace all possible `string` to `wstring` or `wchar_t *` with `L"where possible"` and to convert this `entry.path().relative_path().string()` to `entry.path().relative_path().wstring()` and also `cout` to `wcout`. Still not working.

Also changed `main` to `wmain( int argc, wchar_t *argv[ ])` or to `wmain( int argc, wchar_t *argv[ ], wchar_t *envp[ ] )` and still not working.

Also added `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` after the main function as the other article on stackoverflow says and still no improvement.

I am asking for help because I didn't find a solution for this problem and also, more of the other solution are for printing special unicode characters to console but I need more to work with them (read files names and paths that contain special unicode characters) instead of printing them.

More than this, after I tried all of these possible  not working solutions I am talking about above and reverted my program back to the original code that I just posted above now it is not working at all. It says "no such file or directory" even for normal latin characters and doesn't copy or delete anything at all anymore.

Comment: *CMakeLists in CLion* -- You didn't state what brand of compiler you're using, version of the compiler, etc.  CLion is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: Is special character from input or when iterating over directory content?

Comment: Also, if the issue is deleting a certain file, why all of this code?  Why not a simple 3 line program, with the filename hardcoded, and a simple attempt to delete that file?  The first thing a programmer would do with something like this is to create a small example, before wasting their time writing code to recurse directories.

Comment: `std::string new_path = target + "\\" + entry.path().relative_path().string();` should probably be `std::filesystem::path new_path = target / entry.path().relative_path();`. No need to convert back to `std::string` (apply to most places).

Comment: `180000ms` -> `3min` (better match the comment).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am using x86_64-w64-mingw32 basically MingW which comes with embarcadero DevC++ but I use it in CLion instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, there may be special characters on directory names and/or in file names. Didn't knew that you can write 3min. I am copy from one drive to another and I want to keep the folder structure same as the source which I am copy from. That is why I tried to convert to new path using relative path and source.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wrote so many lines because I have a hard drive that has problems and from time to time it goes offline and back online and while it is offline the program still throwing errors.

Comment: @YoYoYo -- Another thing is this -- it is kind of dangerous to run a program that will delete entire directories, when the program itself is not working 100%.  Hopefully the arguments you are passing are for directories where you don't care if things don't work out correctly.

Comment: Encoding from input console might be an issue. that is why I ask if your issue come from input, or from `fs::recursive_directory_iterator(source)` iteration. conversion from/into `std::string`/`filesystem`should be minimized to reduce source of issue.

Comment: Oh no, input is ok. I just give the path like myprogram.exe C:\myFolders  D:\targetFolder but while iterating through folder structure from C:\myFolders it may meet folders or files with special characters, in fact it really does since it is throwing errors about this only for files or folders with special characters in their names.

Comment: *" I wrote so many lines because"*. You might present us only the `create_directories` for only first args (removing the loops). You might even create subfunction, Check with debugger which string/path is suspicious. You can isolate the function which throw the error (`GetDriveType`, `fs::*`, ...).*

Comment: After fixing the typos pointed out by @Jarod42 and also fixing the `args.erase(args.end());` out-of-bounds vector access, I changed `string` to `wstring`, string literals to `L"..."`, `GetDriveType` to `GetDriveTypeW`, `cout` to `wcout`, and the program ran fine. It copied files and directories named ☺ and ☺.txt.

Comment: @RaymondChen Didn't know that there is a problem with args.erase(args.end()); too. Could you post the modified code, please? I did the same modifications and still not working at all. Except args.erase(args.end()); which didn't know there is a problem too. Thank you so much!

Comment: Look what were the modifications I was talking about above (which didn't work): https://pastebin.com/RzMevCsd

Comment: `GetDriveType(const_cast<char *>(path.root_path().string().c_str()))` -- you forget to upgrade this to `GetDriveTypeW`/`wchar_t`/`wstring`.

Comment: The `const_cast` is unnecessary, you can use the return value of `c_str()` as-is, eg: `GetDriveTypeA(path.root_path().string().c_str())` or `GetDriveTypeW(path.root_path().wstring().c_str())` or simpler `GetDriveTypeW(path.root_path().c_str())`

Comment: Forgot to say that I changed GetDriveType as you say to GetDriveTypeW(path.root_path().wstring().c_str()) in both conditional loop and it doesn't compile because it throws the error: C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v7-git20191109/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'. I am talking about the program from this link: https://pastebin.com/RzMevCsd   Any help, please? Thank you in advance! L.E.: I added -municode in the CMakeLists.txt as compiler arguments and now it compiles well but it doesn't copy any file at all.

Comment: It says "'filesystem error: cannot copy file: No such file or directory" for any file I try to copy and delete, even for those with normal non special characters. Any idea what's happening? Sorry for disturbing you again with this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau could you post the full working code, please? It shows to me "a standard exception was caught, with message 'filesystem error: cannot copy fil
e: No such file or directory'" no matter I do. Thank you so much!

Comment: @YoYoYo I suggest you print out the paths you are trying to copy/delete. You will likely find that they are not what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the header file in which `std::filesystem::path` is defined.
   (possibly in: `PATH_TO_MINGW/usr/include/c++/YOUR_VERSION/bits/fs_path`)
2. Look for `using value_type =`
3. Look for compiler macros that define which `value_type` is ultimately used.

an example from the version from my system:

```
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_FILESYSTEM_IS_WINDOWS
    using value_type = wchar_t;
    static constexpr value_type preferred_separator = L'\\';
#else
```

When the macro `_GLIBCXX_FILESYSTEM_IS_WINDOWS` is set to `1` then a `wchar_t` will be used, which should solve your issue.

Comment: I just read that piece of code you are talking about and it is exactly the same you posted above. Now, what should I do? Please read the comments from the post above and also the pastebin link to see full source code. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I'm not quite sure of what you mean..
Follow the steps from above and find out the name of the macro + the if-clause that encloses `using value_type = wchar_t;`.
In your CMakeLists.txt set:
`target_compile_definitions(YOUR_PROJECT_NAME PRIVATE THE_MACRO=1)`

Comment: The code is exactly the same: using value_type = wchar_t; etc. I tried to set in CMakeLists target_compile_definitions as you say and it throws this error: "Cannot specify compile definitions for target "prg_tst" which is not built
  by this project." prg_tst is the name of the program I am trying to build.  Look, I modified the code exactly I was advised until now in the comments above and it doesn't work. This is the code, if not bother and you are kindly to take a look at: https://pastebin.com/M4GLyZKn  Could you help me, please? It compiles but it doesn't copy anything. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it isn't `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME`, it should say `YOUR_CMAKE_TARGET`. I suspect that in your case the target is defined with a call to `add_executable(YOUR_CMAKE_TARGET)` somewhere in your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @YoYoYo Instead of adding it to your CMakeLists.txt, you can set said macro **before** including filesystem-path (`#include <filesystem>`) in the source code files: `#define THE_MACRO 1`